# 1980s sci-fi show about a family transported through a pyramid?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I saw part of a show sometime in the 80s (early or late, I couldn't say) that I have been trying to remember for some time.  Figured I never would, because no Google search I ever tried had ever turned up anything, but then the other day a friend mentioned the same show that he had been trying to remember, which rekindled my interest.

Here's what I remember:

- A family is going somewhere with a pyramid (Egypt, museum, etc) and in the process they get lost and come out in an alternate world.
- When they come out, they are lined up with others who are "just starting out" as well.  The dad asks one of the people in charge if they all came through the pyramid but does not get a real answer.
- We learn later that the other people are actually robots/androids.
- There is a teenage boy in the family who starts to fall for one of the other "people" but gets upset when he finds out she is not really human.  During their "breakup", she makes a comment like, "If you prick us do we not bleed?" and he responds, "Yeah, battery acid!"
- The real human family ends up escaping the town, narrowly avoiding the "robot police" who want to "dismantle" them.

That's about all that I remember.  I'm pretty sure it was TV, not movie, and that is where the episode ended.  I think it was supposed to be part of a new series at the time, something like a Twilight Zone, but I don't know if it continued much beyond that episode.

Comment: YES!! I've been trying to remember this as well. It aired in South Africa in the 80s. I remember the teenaged boy singing songs by The Monkeys and The Beatles and this was banned on this planet. I also remember their food being in foil packages?
THANKS!! I would love to watch it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like [**Otherworld**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherworld_%28TV_series%29) (1985):

> [image: Otherworld] <sup>[[Source](http://www.losttv-forum.com/forum/showthread.php?p=3184051)]</sup>
>
> ... **the Sterling family take a tour of the interior of the Great Pyramid of Giza** at the same time as a once-in-ten-thousand-years conjunction of the planets.
>
> Inside, they are abandoned by their guide, and as they try to get out, **they are mysteriously transported to another planet which may or may not be in a parallel universe**.
>
> [...]
>
> There is mention in the first episode of a race of humans that created primitive robots and then died out. Eventually **the robots became bored and evolved themselves through continued upgrades and modifications until they created what is known as a plasmoid being: an android that was a biomechanical equivalent of a true human in almost every aspect.**

- [Watch a few clips and the *Intro*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NskxBVKpUYc)

Comment: That definitely sounds like the right one!  Good to know that there were other episodes. Now I'll have to go see if it's available to watch online or track down one of the DVD sets.  Thanks!